# Cannot run docker with the postman/newman image

Tags: linux, docker, newman

I want to run docker locally with postman/newman image but have an error.

```
docker run \
-v /c/MyFullPath/test:/etc/newman \
-t postman/newman run Any_Collection.json
```

Error:

```
error: collection could not be loaded
  unable to read data from file "Any_Collection.json"
  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Any_Collection.json'
```

[Here screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egaTj.png)

I've done it by official tutorial from docker documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You needs to specify full path of container which was a docker volume file path.

This command will work.

```
docker run \
-v /c/MyFullPath/test:/etc/newman \
-t postman/newman run /etc/newman/Any_Collection.json
```

Demo on windows with DOS Prompt.

```
docker run -v /d/temp/answer262:/etc/newman -t postman/newman run /etc/newman/1-test.postman_collection.json
```

So it means volume from `/d/temp/answer262` to `/etc/newman` in container.

Add run `newman` with `/etc/newman/1-test.postman_collection.json` file.

[image]

Run in the Windows 11 with PowerShell
[image]

File location in local.

[image]

This is my docker version

```
docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:09:02 2022
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.12.0 (85629)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:23 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.8
  GitCommit:        9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Test Windows 11 version

[image]

Comment: So it also doesn't work for me with the same error :D
But I have tried with yaml file and there it works. (took code from this guy https://nikiforovall.github.io/dotnet/docker/testing/2021/11/27/testing-with-newman.html)
In a yaml I have run Any_Collection.json without /etc/newman/ path.
But I should resolve this problem with docker command, for me it's important to execute collection directly from CLI.

Comment: Which OS and which terminal using it for docker run?

Comment: Win11 with Ubuntu / cmd / powerShell (wsl integration)

Comment: I tested on Windows 11 and Power Shell as attached image. It works too.

Comment: I added my docker and windows version.